# Lingustic term for three consecutive synonyms used in a sentence?

Tags: synonyms, phrasing

If I recall correctly, in David Brin's "The Uplift War", a species called the Gubru frequently use sentences in which three consecutive synonyms appear to emphasize a topic--presumably a grammatical predisposition on the part of the race. Their language is translated into English (of course) for the reader and might read something like this: *"This is terrible, disastrous, dreadful!"* (This is an example, not a sentence appearing in the book.) I once stumbled upon an established term that described this triplet usage of consecutive synonyms--and wish I had committed it to paper (or memory). What word might this be?

Comment: I can't come up with a term for this, not specifically for a triad, but in general, it's the very common literary technique of **using synonyms for emphasis**.

Comment: This question may belong on [writers.se]

Answer (score 1):

I think the term you're looking for is:

[**pleonasm**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pleonasm):

*the use of more words than are necessary to convey meaning (e.g. see with one's eyes), either as a fault of style or for emphasis.*

Your three synonyms in a row aren't the only type of pleonasm, but this construct certainly fits the definition.  An example sentence from the linked article:

> "Let me tell you this, when social workers offer you, **free, gratis**
>   and **for nothing**, something to hinder you from swooning, which with
>   them is an obsession, it is useless to recoil ..." —Samuel Beckett,
>   Molloy.

Comment: I'm fairly sure the actual term is "redundant tautological pleonasm"... ;)

Answer (score 0):

The word you're trying to remember could be [*hendiatris*](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/hendiatris#English), although that doesn't inherently require the three words in the phrase to be synonyms. To make that explicit you could say *tautological hendiatris*, but that particular noun phrase doesn't appear to be indexed by Google.

Answer (score -1):

I would call this 'the chain of synonyms'. There's a stylistic term 'climax' as well.

Comment: "Chain of synonyms" has an altogether different meaning. Please check.